# seeing full results on R

Tags: r, biostrings

running this code on R, using the Biostrings package,

```r
vmatchPattern("GAAGACCGAGGCCACGCGGAGTACGAACGAGGGTACAGTCTTC", mySeq)
```

in the console, it writes:

```r
...
<22 more elements>
```

How can I see all the results? The `print` function returns the same result.

Answer (score 4):

It returns an IRanges object. You can transform it to a data.frame using `as.data.frame()` and then either write as a file with something like `write.table()` to view outside of R or use `View()` in RStudio to explore it.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Accept the answer to provide closure to the port. @FarzadBeikpour